# how to remove an entry from my PATH in Python?

Tags: python, windows

I know I can use

```
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + "C:\\Users\\john\\myprog\\bin"
```

to add this folder to the (python representation of the) `PATH`. However, how can I remove an entry from the `PATH`?

Using :

```
os.environ.pop('C:\\Users\\john\\myprog\\bin')
```

does not work here. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.environ['PATH']` is a `str` object, it doesn't contain a `pop()` method.

What you want to do instead is split it, remove the last element and then assign a new `str` to the `os.environ['PATH']` like so:

```
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + "C:\\Users\\john\\myprog\\bin"

# do something...

os.environ['PATH'] = os.pathsep.join(os.environ['PATH'].split(os.pathsep)[:-1])
```

You could do it that way... but I would recommend using `sys` instead:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(my_dir)

# do what you need

sys.path.remove(my_dir)
```

Comment: `sys.path` is searched by the interpreter when importing modules. It has nothing to do with the `PATH` environment variable, which the system uses when searching for files.